# Counting Operations

Tags: computational-complexity, numerical-calculus

Good Evening,

Context:

I wanted to count the operations for calculate the coefficents in the newton base if you have $n+1$ datas.

[image]

$$f_j=p_j(x_j)=a_0+\sum_{i=1}^j(a_i\prod_{k=0}^{{i-1}}(x_j-x_k))\ \ \ j,i=1,..,n$$

maybe you can help me to understand the counting in my script, because I have another solution.
I want to count how many operations I need to calculate this:

$$a_j=\frac{f_j-a_0-\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}(a_i\prod_{k=0}^{i-1}(x_j-x_k)}{\prod_{k=0}^{j-1}(x_j-x_k)}$$

I would say, we have in the deonominator $j$ subtractions and $j-1$ multiplications.
In the numerator we have $1+2+...+(j-1)$ Subtractions and also $1+2+...+(j-1)$ multiplications and then $j$ subtractions and in the end one Divsion.

Thats what I found in my script, but does not the 1 subtraction $-a_0$ is missing?

Thanks for helping me!:)

Comment: Can you give us some context? I'm presuming that there is some algorithm that you are attempting to find the computational complexity of.

Comment: Yes, of course. It is about interpolation in newton base. And the $aj$ are the coefficents

\begin{align*}
 
 f_0=p_0(x_0)=a_0\\ 
f_1=p_1(x_1)=a_0+a_1(x_1-x_0)\\ 
f_2=p_2(x_2)=a_0+a_1(x_2-x_0)+a_2(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)\\
\ \vdots\\
{f_n=p_n(x_n)=a_0+a_1(x-x_0)+a_2(x-x_0)(x-x_1)+\\ \     \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ...+a_n(x-x_0)(x-x_1)...(x-x_{n-1})}


\end{align*}

Comment: Can you put that as the first part of your question?

Comment: I hope its better to understand now.